# Image View is rendering in Xcode Preview, but not on-device?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos, swiftui

Disclaimer: I am on the latest beta of MacOS, iOS, and Xcode, but I wanted to get some input to see if this might be user error before I filed a bug report as I am quite new to both Swift and iOS development.

Hello all, I'm working on developing an app to view and manipulate files on my Samba server. I'm aware that the built-in Files app does have this functionality, but it does have a couple of shortcomings and ways that I think it could be improved, plus I thought it would be a great exercise to learn some of the intricacies of developing for the iOS platform.

With that out of the way, I am working on one of the basic features that would show an image to the user after they tap on the file in a list. My code seems to fetch and display the image just fine, but only in the Preview of Xcode! If I use either the Live Previews feature of Xcode with a connected iOS device or Build the app and try to access the Image View, nothing renders. I have tried searching online for anyone that has perhaps experienced a similar issue, but have not had any luck finding anyone.

I'll attach both screenshots of the editor and of the phone so that you know I'm not insane as well as the code for the troublesome view. If this does turn out not to be user error, I will of course file it in the Feedback app, but I just wanted to make sure first.

[Xcode Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKRzW.jpg)
[Xcode Previews App on iOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7lU9.png)

```
//
//  ImageView.swift
//  Akasha
//
//  Created by Dylan on 6/20/23.
//

import SwiftUI
import AMSMB2
import Combine

struct ImageView: View {
    @ObservedObject var imageLoader: ImageLoader
    @State var image: UIImage = UIImage()
    
    init(withUrl url: String) {
        imageLoader = ImageLoader(urlString: url)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(uiImage: image)
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .onReceive(imageLoader.didChange) { data in
                    self.image = UIImage(data: data) ?? UIImage()
            }
            Spacer()
            Text("Hello World!")
        }
    }
}

class ImageLoader: ObservableObject {
    var didChange = PassthroughSubject<Data, Never>()
    var data = Data() {
        didSet {
            didChange.send(data)
        }
    }
    
    let client = AMSMB2(url: URL(string: "smb://10.0.0.2/")!, credential: URLCredential(user: "user", password: "password", persistence: .forSession))

    init(urlString:String) {
        guard let url = URL(string: fetchImage(path: urlString).absoluteString) else { return }
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { [weak self] data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, self != nil else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                self?.data = data
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
    
    func fetchImage(path: String) -> URL {
        do {
            var cacheURLDirectory: URL
            cacheURLDirectory = try FileManager.default.url(for: .cachesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
            let fullCacheURLPath = cacheURLDirectory.absoluteString + path
            let fullCacheURL = URL(string: fullCacheURLPath)!
            client?.connectShare(name: "media") { error in
                if error != nil {
                    print("connectShare Error: ")
                    print(error!)
                }
                self.client?.downloadItem(atPath: path, to: fullCacheURL, progress: AMSMB2.ReadProgressHandler(downloadProgressHandler(bytes:total:)), completionHandler: AMSMB2.SimpleCompletionHandler(downloadCompletionHandler(error:)))
            }
            return fullCacheURL
        } catch {
            print ("Error Setting Cache Directory for Image")
            return URL(string: "")!
        }
        
        func downloadProgressHandler(bytes: Int64, total: Int64) -> Bool {
            return true
        }
        
        func downloadCompletionHandler(error: Error?) -> Void {
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ImageView(withUrl: "Old Hard Drive.webp")
}
```

You may also be wondering why I am not just using AsyncImage as introduced in iOS 15. I did actually try that and while it did display both in the preview and on-device, it would flicker whenever I would touch the device and sometimes after the flicker, it would leave the image partially unloaded and gray. I think this would be a more stable solution if I could just get this kink worked out.

Other users online suggested it may be an issue with App Transport Security possibly being disabled on the Mac but enabled on iOS. I added the suggested items to the info.plist from the linked Apple Developer article, but alas, the issue remained. That did get me thinking that if it is not a bug with Xcode itself, it could possibly be a configuration issue with my project, and I did try to research possible configuration issues that would lead to what I am experiencing, but I couldn't find anything, and I am not even sure where to being debugging that with all the options and levers and knobs in the Project Settings.

Thanks for taking the time to read this everyone.

Comment: Why not make it simpler: instead of `@State var image` in `ImageLoader` change `data` to `@Published var data` and remove `didChange`. Also it's quite wasteful to render image from bytes on every re-rendering of the view. It's better to preserve UIImage (or even Image) in your `ImageLoader`

Comment: @timbretimbre Dude, I could hug you right now. That fixed my issue completely! They are loading both in the preview and on-device faster and better than ever! You're amazing! I am not sure how I mark your answer as the one that solved my question though.

Comment: You're also retaining the `ImageLoader` as an `ObservedObject` instead of a `StateObject`, which could cause problems, too